# Boolean object in javascript returns true for "false" parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem.

I have situations where my ajax calss returns a string.

sometimes that string is "false"
i want to always convert that string value into a boolean
i tried : new Boolean(thatValue)

but it returns true even for "false" as a paremter

is there anyway to solve this? except me writing my own custom function that will return false if "flase" ?..

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this you've already described:

```
if(value === 'true') {
  //do something
}
```

Or:

```
if(value !== 'false') {
  //do something
}
```

You're limited by JavaScript's weak typing here, actually working to your disadvantage, where any non-empty string will convert to a `true` boolean, even if that string is `"false"`.

To get it and store it for use elsewhere, something like this works:

```
var myBool = value !== "false";
```

Answer (score 4):

A string is always true if it contains some text, even if that text is "false". You can check for it using the ternary operator:

```
thatValue == "false" ? false : true
```