# Why does `new Boolean("false")` retruns `true`?

Tags: javascript, boolean

My code is:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([new Number(3), new Boolean("true"), new String("X")]));
console.log(JSON.stringify([new Number(3), new Boolean("false"), new String("X")]));
```

And the output is:

```
[3, true, "X"]
[3, true, "X"]
```

Why does the second output show `true` instead of `false`? I am new to JS, pardon my mistake.

Comment: Beacuse you're passing a truthy value to the boolean constructor. Pass ex. 0 to get false.

Comment: "false" !== false

Comment: it should be new Boolean(false)  for false.

Comment: You cannot pass a value to the boolean constructor in string form. By default, `new Boolean()` returns a value of `false`. You can also pass `0` or `1` to the Boolean constructor to get the expected result.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+new+boolean%28false%29+returns+true) of [Boolean("false") returns true.. any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38649913/4642212). Also related: [Boolean object in javascript returns true for "false" parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3343571/4642212).

Comment: @SaadKhalid Yes, you *can* pass a string. However, the value will be converted based on its truthyness. The same thing happens with `0` and `1` - the former is falsy, the latter is truthy. The result, however, is a boolean object, not a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

As Teemu mentioned, `"false"` is not equal to `false`.

You don’t need the data type; just put in the values you want directly in the array.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([3, true, "X"]));
console.log(JSON.stringify([3, false, "X"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Only `null , false, 0, -0, undefined , NaN, ""` is a falsey value.

```js
// it should be 
 new Boolean(false); 
// it should not be
 new Boolean("false");
```

Comment: … and `0n` and `document.all`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Answer (score 0):

The `Boolean` constructor casts a value to a boolean via its truthiness or falsiness; it does not parse strings. You can think of it like this:

```js
function Boolean(x) {
    if (x) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You wouldn't expect that code to return `false` if `x` were `"false"`, right? The only falsy values in JS are:

- 0 (and 0n)
- null
- undefined
- false itself
- NaN
- and the empty string ""

If you do want to parse a string, then you can just do `x == "true"`:

```js
"true" == "true" // true
"false" == "true" // false
```